# Extract project name from URL

Tags: java, string, split

I have URL

```
../p/xmlProj/bugs/...
```

I'm looking for a way to extract the project name into single variable using java code
I tried this

```
String url = "/p/xmlProject/bugs/";
final String[] projName = url.split("/",3);
```

But i didn't work for me !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this 3 there. Simply write:

```
final String[] projName = url.split("/");
```

And the project name will be `projName[3]`.

Comment: Won't it be in position 1 (0 = p, 1 = xmlProject)?  If you're confident of the shape of the string, try `final String projName = url.split("/")[1];`

Comment: @PaulHicks The resulted array will be ["", "p", "xmlProject", "bugs", ""]. I assume that "bugs" is the project's name.